# How to integrate exporting to csv with backend list in octobercms

Tags: laravel, export-to-csv, octobercms, octobercms-backend

I am a beginner of OctoberCMS and I am going to use export feature in backend list. I have read document about [importing and exporting](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/import-export) in backend of octobercms.

But I am not sure how to use this feature and I want to know followings.

1. How to add export button on backend list.
2. How to integrate exporting with backend list.

I hope your kind assistance.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Steps [here we need to export `TimeLog` model data]

Reference : [Tutorialmeta.com](https://tutorialmeta.com/october-cms/integrate-import-export-csv-backend-list-octobercms)

> **1.** Add this lines to your controller

```
// if you have more behaviors add this one as extra
public $implement = [
    'Backend.Behaviors.ImportExportController',
];

// your config
public $importExportConfig = 'config_import_export.yaml';
```

> **2.** Now inside your config `config_import_export.yaml`

```
export:
    title: Export TimeLog
    modelClass: HardikSatasiya\TimeTracker\Models\TimeLogExport
    list: $/hardiksatasiya/timetracker/models/timelog/columns.yaml
    redirect: hardiksatasiya/timetracker/timelog
```

> **3.** `$/hardiksatasiya/timetracker/models/timelog/columns.yaml` we will use default list model fields so no changes here.

---

> **4.** Now you need to put file `export.htm` in views directory with this content

```
<?= Form::open(['class' => 'layout']) ?>

    <div class="layout-row">
        <?= $this->exportRender() ?>
    </div>

    <div class="form-buttons">
        <button
            type="submit"
            data-control="popup"
            data-handler="onExportLoadForm"
            data-keyboard="false"
            class="btn btn-primary">
            Export records
        </button>
    </div>

<?= Form::close() ?>
```

> **5.** Now you need `any button/ menu` which can redirect you to `export` action of your controller, as we are implementing `import-export` behavior our controller can have `export` and `import` actions.

```
Next
```

> so you can point to this url an you can see export screen `http://localhost/backend/<author_name>/<plugin_name>/<controller_name>/export`
> **OR BETTER** you can add export button on toolbar which can redirect you to export screen **[use this docu to modify your list toolbar https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/lists#adding-toolbar]**

[image]

### If you like more default things

what you can do is just follow **step 1** then in **step 2** use this settings

```
export:
    useList: true
```

then you can skip all other config

> **last step** you just need **to point to export url** -> `http://localhost/backend/<author_name>/<plugin_name>/<controller_name>/export` to generate CSV no question asked that url will read all info from list config and `let you directly download export.csv file`

for multiple list export and other stuff read this docu: https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/import-export#list-behavior-integration

if any further questions please add comment

Comment: Thank you for your answer. it will be help to me, I want to know how to use export option- useList. If you know that, would you explain me?

Comment: added other section `If you like more default things` please read it it will help you.